# PDO and security

Tags: php, pdo

I was attacked this morning and had some JS injected into my site. I'm trying to track down the hole and patch it. I am under the impression that the PDO below is secure, can someone confirm or deny this?

```
        //Adding the lead to the local database
        $leads = array($firstName, $lastName, $company, $state, $country, $phone, $email, $industry, $uniqueId, $comments );

        $qry = $dbh->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO leads (FirstName, LastName, Company, State, Country, Phone, Email, Industry, Solution, Comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        if(!($qry->execute($leads))) {
            print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        }
```

Comment: As that query stands, it's "secure". But SQL injection is but one of a few zillion attack vectors for infecting a site, so you'd better look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's secure in the sense that someone won't be able to inject a SQL query - but it's not going to stop them from putting HTML into any of your fields. You might want to look into using something like [strip_tags](http://ca.php.net/strip_tags) to prevent HTML from being stored, or doing some extra sanitization before you display it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

PDO doesn't protect you from JavaScript injections. It protects you from SQL injections. It will put the dangerous JS into your database without issue since PDO doesn't concern itself with what is and is not dangerous JS. That is not its job. You need to find other ways to prevent malicious JS from being displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously secure from SQLI but not from XSS or tainted input. It just means the attacker might not be able to taint your SQL Query. But the output part might be tainted. Check your output escaping/sanatization methods!